# T-SQL: Access DB objects in same schema without qualifying?

Tags: sql-server, namespaces

I have a project with many stored procedures, functions, views and tables.

I currently have the project deployed within a database all within the same schema. For this example we'll call it "mainproject"

Now, I've been tasked with creating a duplicate project *in the same database*. The obvious solution is to clone all objects into another schema. I've been able to do this using some SQL scripts. So now I have another schema called "secondproject" containing all the objects from the first schema.

The problem is, in all of my functions, views and procedures, the original schema is referenced, e.g. `DECLARE @someVar INT = mainproject.getId(@someObject)`, `SELECT someColumn FROM mainproject.someTable`, `UPDATE mainproject.someTable SET someColumn = @someValue WHERE someOtherColumn = @someOtherValue` So executing the functions ends up referencing the incorrect schema.

Going through hundreds of views, procs and functions to find and replace all occurrences of the schema `mainproject` would be a tedious and potentially unreliable process.

My question is, is there a way to specify "within the current schema" when referencing any object?

Just doing `DECLARE @someVar INT = getId(@someObject)` results in `'getId' is not a recognized built-in function name.` and I can't even save the procedure.

---

EDIT: The first answer below helps shed a little light on the situation. If you don't specify a schema on access to an object it assumes it's in your default schema.

The problem is that on the production server against which I will be running my DDL script, the server's default schema for my user account is `dbo`. The application user only has access to DML statements so I cannot use that account to run the create script.

I suppose if there's no way to have a stored procedure assume unqualified objects are in the same schema it resides in, I'll have to resort to find/replace after generating a script....

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you're talking about schemas. If none is specified, the database engine will default to whatever the current User's default schema is. By default, that's dbo. In short, if you have objects with the same name in different schemas, you'll need to specify the schema you want to use in your query.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, I was referring to schemas. It looks like you're right, the issue is I'm developing on the server under "my" account, which has its default schema set to `dbo`. I will try creating another user account in the database to develop under with the default schema set.

Comment: Ok, the problem I've discovered is that this will work fine for my local instance but it will not for the production server. I only get one user account there, with its default schema on the single database set to `dbo`. The application user which the admin created only has DML statement access, so I can't use it to run the DDL queries to create the database. Since SQL Server won't even let me create stored procedures that reference objects it doesn't believe exists, I'm still stuck...

Comment: I suppose you could make all of your queries dynamic sql, with the dynamic portion being the schema. I think that's probably more effort and more messy than just find-and-replacing the schema and running it after. Not being able to have multiple logins for you will make this very difficult.